# How to make ScriptEventHookProvider work?

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

I have Nifi and Nifi Registry deployed via Docker. I'm trying to integrate ScriptEventHookProvider.
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-registry-docs/html/administration-guide.html#scripteventhookprovider

Here is my providers.xml:

[image]

Referenced script file **notify.sh** exists and is placed inside of the registry container:

[image]

I tried relative and absolute paths, but nothing helps me - I get the error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-current/registry_hooks/notify.sh": error=2, No such file or directory
```

[image]

**So my question is, how to set script path and working directory correctly? Why do we need both of them?**

Answer (score 2):

Problem was in .sh file: it requires LF endings. I had CRLF. So I converted line endings using VS code, and now everything works fine.

[image]